# Typescript in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

Can we write typescript in open source LWC?

I believe we can't in salesforce specific LWC. When I try to install LWC via npx lwc-create-app my-app, I don't see `tsconfig.json`.

So I wanted to check if we can use typescript in LWC?

Comment: You mean for Salesforce app or app outside Salesforce ?

Comment: app outside Salesforce. I think we  can't use typescript for salesforce app (as mentioned in the doc)

Comment: Hi @RakeshBoinepalli - were you able to find any documentation in regards to support for typescript for LWC OSS?

Answer (score 1):

For OSS LWC: It is planned to release typescript support in the next couple of weeks (so monitor the github page of the lwc-create-app) #safeharbor

For On Platform LWC: Most likely never because updates often bring "breaking" changes and therefore salesforce consider typescript as too "unstable" to be provided on their platform

Comment: Thank you. Just want to make sure is this the right git page :  https://github.com/muenzpraeger/lwc-create-app/tree/master/packages/lwc-create-app ?